# Cucumber Strange Behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

While using cucumber for BDD, i have found a very strange scenario where my "I should see" method (default implementation is failling).

Here is my scenario definition:

```
  When I go to signup page
  And I fill in "Username" with "ben@test.com"
  And I press "Sign up"
  Then I should see "Anything that i type here. ABC XYZ"
```

Obviously, the text  "Anything that i type here. ABC XYZ" is not on the page but the cucumber wouldnt fail the scenario. Here is the definition of "I should see"

```
Then /^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |text|
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.should have_content(text)
  else
    assert page.has_content?(text)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more digging, and it seems that the problem is that 1.8.7 is not supported in capybara. Instead of complaining loudly, it simply performs badly. Things like filling in forms work etc but the `has_content` fails miserably. Maybe it would be better if it shouted loudly that it needed 1.9.x.

Anyway I changed my Gemfile to

`gem "capybara", "1.1.4", :group => :test`

and it all seems to be working again.

Should I log this as an issue against capybara? The idea would be to just scream that it wont work with 1.8.7.

More on this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cukes/B3UbbyG5k6s